# Django unable to server files in media directory but serving content from static directory

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have the following code in my `settings.py` file

```
MEDIA_ROOT_PATH = MEDIA_FILES = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "media")
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT_PATH
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT_PATH = STATIC_FILES = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static")
STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT_PATH
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and this line in the `urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The developement server is able to serve contents from the `/static/` directory but not `/media/` directory how can I add that to the urls.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your url patterns:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: I did this but I wanted to know isn't there any other way something similar to `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`

Comment: There is no media files version of the django.contrib.staticfiles app in Django, which is probably the reason there is no similar mediafiles_urlpatterns() available (though it would be easy for development).